# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Save changes problem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

This is my class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Student_InfoFORM
{
    public partial class tblStudentform
    {
        public static void createStudentform(string idno, string fname, string mname, string lname, string add, string email)
        {
            Student_InfoFORM.studentFormEntities container = new Student_InfoFORM.studentFormEntities();

            tblStudentform std = new tblStudentform
            {
                stud_id = idno,
                firstname = fname,
                midname = mname,
                lastname = lname,
                address = add,
                emailadd = email
            };

            container.tblStudentforms.AddObject(std);
            container.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message from the `SaveChanges()` call:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

and this is the inner exception every time I save the data entered in my application:

> System.Data.UpdateException was unhandled by user code
> HResult=-2146233087
> Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
> Source=System.Data.Entity
>
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
> at Student_InfoFORM.tblStudentform.createStudentform(String idno, String fname, String mname, String lname, String add, String email) in C:\Users\admin2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Student_InfoFORM\Student_InfoFORM\tblStudentform.cs:line 24
> at Student_InfoFORM._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\admin2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Student_InfoFORM\Student_InfoFORM\Default.aspx.cs:line 19
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=-2146232060
> Message=String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
> ErrorCode=-2146232060
> Class=16 LineNumber=1 Number=8152
> Procedure=""Server=\SQLEXPRESSState=14
>
> StackTrace:
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)InnerException:

Comment: String or binary data truncated will appear when your field size is less than value you are trying to insert. One of the strings size in database is less than what you are passing

Comment: Yes. That is also showing in the browser when it stops loading.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: Check which field size is less in database. Some varchar(100) maybe and increase it or decrease input from code

Comment: Thanks! The varchar did work unlike the char that I put earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are passing either a wrong type or data that is too big for the current column. I would recommend using nvarchar whenever available for strings. In case you need to change the column size you can use

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName TypeName(Size)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much better solution.

Comment: I got a similar issue however, it stops at DBContext.SaveChanges(); I have no idea why it would do that